# How to add objects with more than one attribute to an array

Tags: java, arrays, object

I'm new to java and having trouble with arrays. I have a Fish class and a Tank class.  The Fish class holds two fields, a String name and an int weight.  In the Tank class I have to write a method that adds  Fish objects to an array not an ArrayList.  Later on I have to write methods returning the name and the weight of the Fish Objects at specific indexes and also a method that returns an ArrayList of objects in the array.  I've already written the Fish class but am not sure how to add Objects with name and weight into an array. Any help would be great, Thanks.

Comment: Can you please post a sample of code?

Answer (score 2):

you just need an array like this:

```
 Fish[] fishes = new Fish[size];
```

then you need to create new object from `Fish` and set its attributes by its setters and add to the array like this:

```
Fish fish1= new Fish();
.
setting attributes
.
fishes[0]= fish1;
```

and so on.